# What is the difference between ALTER INDEX and DBCC DBREINDEX?

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, index

Is the only difference between

```
ALTER INDEX [index_name] on [object_name] REBUILD with (ONLINE=OFF, FILLFACTOR=90)
```

and

```
DBCC DBREINDEX([dbname], 90)
```

just that the DBCC command will reindex all of the indexes on all of the tables in the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DBCC command is a consistency checker utility inside of SQL Server whereas ALTER is a DDL SQL command.  The DBCC REINDEX command was deprecated in a previous version so it is not as robust as the new ALTER INDEX command is today.  There is more functionality in the ALTER INDEX than the DBCC REINDEX commands:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx

Happy indexing!

Comment: I assumed as much, but just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

The first is current usage, the second was deprecated in SQL 2005.